# Is it possible for an element in xaml to bind against several paths?

Tags: xaml, binding, path

In XAML, I have a button that is already bound to a path "HasWritePermission" on it's visibility tag. Is it possible to add another path on the same tag? Say I want to hide the button completely based on some logic.

To give this some context, the button is a delete button that should not be visible if a given list is empty

Comment: Removed Silverlight Tag. MultiBinding does not natively exist in Silverlight, therefore the accepted answer does not apply, and the question must relate to some other platform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at multi binding

```
<DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{Quire_UI_Value_Converters:DiscountConverter}" Mode="TwoWay" NotifyOnSourceUpdated="True" UpdateSourceTrigger="LostFocus">
        <Binding Path="Discount_Taken_Value" Mode="TwoWay"/>
        <Binding Path="Discount_Taken_Type" Mode="TwoWay"/>
    </MultiBinding>
</DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
```